# JSON.NET deserialize results in list with default values

Tags: c#, json.net

Am I missing something obvious here? JSON:

> {"p":[{},{"clientId":102102059663,"checkbox1Ticked":false,"checkbox2Ticked":false},{"clientId":23841,"checkbox1Ticked":false,"checkbox2Ticked":false},{"clientId":102102111426,"checkbox1Ticked":false,"checkbox2Ticked":false}]}

C#: (checkboxData is the string above)

```
    public JsonResult SubmitSelectedChanges(string checkboxData)
    {
        var deserializedClients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChangeList>(checkboxData);
        return null;
    }

    public class ChangeList
    {
        public List<Change> p { get; set; }
    }


    public class Change
    {
        string clientId { get; set; }
        bool checkbox1Ticked { get; set; }
        bool checkbox2Ticked { get; set; }
    }
```

After deserializing the clientId is always null and the checbox1Ticked and checkbox2Ticked is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I had forgotten the access modifiers for the change class:

```
   public class Change
        {
            public string clientId { get; set; }
            public bool checkbox1Ticked { get; set; }
            public bool checkbox2Ticked { get; set; }
        }
```

I would have thought this would have thrown an exception.